# How to combine two javascript regular expression or regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to combine the two regex.

`/^([a-z]{2})?([0-9]+)$/gi` and `/^(?!.*?([0-9])\1{3})\S+$/gi`

something like this `/(([a-z]{2})?([0-9]+)) || ((?!.*?([0-9])\1{3})\S+)/gi` and this `/(([a-z]{2})?([0-9]+)) && ((?!.*?([0-9])\1{3})\S+)/gi`

> **So I need both the above two separate regex combined in one regex format.**
>
> I need both or(||) as well as and(&&).
>
> **what the above regex code actually does is:**
>
> *Below is to check for, not allow more than 3 same character:*

```
/^(?!.*?([0-9])\1{3})\S+$/gi.test("4444") => false
/^(?!.*?([0-9])\1{3})\S+$/gi.test("11222") => true
/^(?!.*?([0-9])\1{3})\S+$/gi.test("77722") => true
```

> *Below is for to check, not more than 2 characters at beginning and followed by only numbers:*

```
/^(([a-z]{1,2})?([0-9]+))$/gi.test('sj76755') => true
/^(([a-z]{1,2})?([0-9]+))$/gi.test('k4545') => true
/^(([a-z]{1,2})?([0-9]+))$/gi.test('6j53') => false
/^(([a-z]{1,2})?([0-9]+))$/gi.test('653aa') => false
/^(([a-z]{1,2})?([0-9]+))$/gi.test('ss653aa') => false
```

> So I need both the above two separate regex combined in one regex
> format.
>
> I need both or(||) as well as and(&&).
>
> Thanks in advance

Comment: Provide some valid and invalid matches in your question

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly what you're after here.  As anubhava mentioned, some examples would be useful.  From a strictly logical standpoint, if you need "logical and" and "logical or" at the same time, it effectively becomes just "logical and".  Is it that you want `0000` or `aa0000`?  Should `aa0` pass?

Comment: this is dupr supr, same question dupr'd a week ago. of course since each regx is different it cant be just  _joined_, yes, no ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***OP Curr regex's :***
( `^(?!.*?([0-9])\1{3})\S+$` , `^(([a-z]{1,2})?([0-9]+))$` )

The **AND :**
note - The minimum is the subset that includes both is the only *required*, dissallow others.
In this case, the two regex minimums are `^\S+$` , `^[a-z]{0,2}[0-9]+$`
where the subset that satisfies both is `^[a-z]{0,2}[0-9]+$`.

After applying the assershun we find the AND regex resolves to this

`^(?!.*?([0-9])\1{3})[a-z]{0,2}[0-9]+$`

[demo1](https://regex101.com/r/C3wlTa/1)

The **OR :**
note - Each regex has it's own pecularity's that make it dificult to
merge functionality. It is possible though to just factor out common
terms that satisfy both.
Each need to be joined with an or metachar `|`.
But, each situation is different, it takes an experienced developer (me)
to find the possibilities.

After factoring we find the OR regex resolves to this

`^(?:(?!.*?([0-9])\1{3})\S+|[a-z]{0,2}[0-9]+)$`

[demo2](https://regex101.com/r/zjLdCp/1)

---

***OP Prev regex's :***
The OR `^([a-z]{2})?([0-9]+)$|[0-9]{4,}`

The AND `^([a-z]{2})?([0-9]{4,})$`

Comment: I just updated my post. could you please help me out with that?

Comment: reviewd new post info, added insite